# Select multiple not working in jquery mobile's listview

Tags: jquery, html, css, listview, jquery-mobile

I'm using JQuery-Mobile and I want to have a `<select multiple><option1><option2>...</select>` in my listview but it doesnt seem to work:

http://jsfiddle.net/73pSv/27/

Does anyone know how to make this work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/73pSv/34/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple is not supported in JQuery Mobile Select.

Here is the reference: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.0a4.1/docs/forms/forms-selects.html

Comment: It's supported in one case, when using a custom select menu `data-native-menu="false"`. http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/selectmenu-custom/ demo http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/73pSv/34/